# Inserting into a list with a multibound generic type

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class structure:

```
class A
{
 ....
} 

interface I
{
 ...
}

class C extends A implements I
{
 ...
}
```

In my class,

```
 class Container<Item extends A & I>
 { 
   void add(List<? super Item> itemsList)
   {
     itemsList.add(new C());
   }
 }
```

The above code throws me a compile time error:

```
 capture<? super Item> in list cannot be applied to C.
```

Why does the above error takes place?

Comment: It's because there's no relationship between `Item` (please use single letter for type parameters) and `C`  in the context of the `add` method.

Comment: C is extending both A and implementing I, so doesn't it satisfy the conditions for itemsList?

Comment: If you had another class `D` that extends `A` and implements `I`, perhaps the container instance would have been `new Container<D>()`. Then inserting `C` would be a clear type violation.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate of the suggested post. OP's problem is the misuse of generics.

Comment: You probably meant to do `List<? super C> as the parameter type.

Comment: So, is there any way I can create a class with multiple bounds and insert C and D both in that container if both C and D extend A and Implement B?

Comment: @TedHopp Is there any other way I can create a multiple bound container which can take both C and D?